# Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory when using slf4j with log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j

I'm starting to use `slf4j` with `log4j2` but I got the problem as below.
What am I wrong or lack somethings of from the pom file?

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory

Reported exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/AbstractLoggerAdapter

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)

at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)

...
```

My pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My very simple code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Study {

    static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Study.class);
    public static void main(String... args) {
        LOGGER.info("hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using different versions `2.12.0` and `2.13.3` is on purpose?

Comment: No, version is no matter

Comment: How do you build the application and how do you run it?

Comment: I just use the run functionality in intelliJ to run the main method (right click in Class Study and run the main())

Comment: Unless you have an existing codebase that is using sl4j you don't really need to use it for log4j2 and in fact you lose a lot of the features of log4j2 if you do. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500347/3284624

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same version for all libs from one groupId:

```
...
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

Also, you can try running without `org.slf4j` dependency. Run `mvn clean install` before the start.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the reason but if I use 2.11.2, it works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```